# Missing Type.GetProperty() method in Windows 8 Developer Preview

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to port a simple application to Windows 8 Metro (WinRT). It seems that some very basic methods are missing. One basic example: `Type.GetProperty()`. It is available for Windows Phone 7, Silverlight and .NET client profile. Do I have to install something (eg. a special library) or is this method simply not available in the .NET metro profile?

**UPDATE**

OK, thank you. Now I use `this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties`.

`using System.Reflection;` is needed to have this `GetTypeInfo()` extension method.

Comment: Sidenote: It is not that simple to port an existing WP7 app to metro. There are not only namespace changes... (Reflection, Streams, Dispatcher, ...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reflection has changed a bit in Metro: see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#reflection) ( "Reflection changes" - near the bottom ).

Basically, you now need: `type.GetTypeInfo()`.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Nicholas Butler response, I ended up using this kind of extensions to maintain the code reusable in all platforms.

```
#if NETFX_CORE // Workaround for .Net for Windows Store not having Type.GetProperty method
    public static class GetPropertyHelper
    {
        public static PropertyInfo GetProperty(this Type type, string propertyName)
        {
            return type.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(propertyName);
        }
    }
#endif
```

This way, `Type.GetProperty()` is implemented for all platforms.

Comment: Granted, this is an old thread, but I should like to add that GetDeclaredPropert(y/ies) will only return properties on current type. Meaning that if Class2 derives from Class1, GetDerivedProperties will only return properties from Class2.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard if you want to search in all properties you can use `type.GetRuntimeProperty(propertyName)`

Comment: Actually I ended up just doing this: for (; type != null; type = type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType)

Comment: How about GetProperties()?

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard Have you tried `GetType().GetRuntimeProperties()`?