# Accessing a class variable by its name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, variables

I'm reading in data from an xml file and have the following switch statement

```
switch (localVariable)
{
    case "myStringVariable":
        myClass.myStringVariable= subReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        break;
    case "myOtherStringVariable":
        myClass.myOtherStringVariable= subReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        break;
    case "myBoolVariable":
        myClass.myBoolVariable= subReader.ReadElementContentAsBool();
        break;
```

I would like to optimize this into something like

```
switch (localVariable)
{
    case "myStringVariable":
    case "myOtherStringVariable":
        myClass.localVariable= subReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        break;
    case "myBoolVariable":
        myClass.localVariable= subReader.ReadElementContentAsBool();
        break;
```

Comment: ok. so do it. use your intuition.

Comment: what is wrong with that code?

Comment: It would be funnier if @DarthVader said "use the force".

Comment: Please clarify if your questions is in regards to: a) Falling through in a switch statement in C#? b) accessing the class variable via the local variable?

Comment: @c0ntinuum it's B, I understand how to fall through a switch statemenet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection to take it a step further:

Add the following method to your class:

```
    private void SetVariableFromReader(string variableName)
    {
        var property = GetType().GetProperty(variableName);
        if (property != null)
        {
            if (typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                property.SetValue(this, subReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
            }
            if (typeof(bool).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                property.SetValue(this, subReader.ReadElementContentAsBool());
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Then, rather than using a switch statement in your code, you just call:

```
SetVariableFromReader(localVariable)
```

Comment: apparently Windows 8 Metro doesn't have the .getProperty or .IsAssignableFrom functionality but thanks the idea

Comment: @Torvos It's not missing, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858469/missing-type-getproperty-c-sharp-method-in-windows-8-developer-preview

Answer (score 2):

Use the [FastMember](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html) library, which is precisely for this purpose and is *WAAAAY* faster than reflection.

Go to Nuget/Package Management console:

```
PM> Install-Package FastMember
```

Then:

```
public class Foo  {
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        var wrapped = ObjectAccessor.Create(f);
        string propName = "Baz";
        wrapped[propName] = "Ah ha";
        Console.WriteLine(f.Baz);  //Prints Ah ha
    }
}
```

Or, in your case:

```
var myWrappedClass = ObjectAccessor.Create(myClass);

        switch (localVariable) {
            case "myStringVariable":
            case "myOtherStringVariable":
                myWrappedClass[localVariable] = subReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                break;
            case "myBoolVariable":
                myWrappedClass[localVariable] = subReader.ReadElementContentAsBool();
                break;
        }
```

Done and done. Really elegant.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want something like this:

```
        switch (localVariable)
        {
             case "myStringVariable":
             case "myOtherStringVariable":
                {
                    myClass.GetType()
                           .GetProperty(localVariable)
                           .SetValue(myClass, 
                                     subReader.ReadElementContentAsString(), 
                                     null);
                    break;
                }
             ...
        }
```

I should agree with others, who tell to avoid Reflection in simple scenarios.

Comment: Hmm Visual Studio 2012 is not offering the .getProperty() option and yes I understand but I see this quickly growing from a few to a large number

Comment: @Torvos Probably some namespace (System.Reflection) is missing. In VS2010 it's not necessary, unfortunately I can't say anything about VS2012. If the number is growing and you insist on this approach, than armen shimoon showed the next step

Comment: @Torvos Reflection has changed in W8Metro, please, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858469/missing-type-getproperty-c-sharp-method-in-windows-8-developer-preview

Comment: agreed, thanks for the info, shame I can't mark both of you as correct

Comment: @Torvos The answer, you chose, is far more complete, so it's OK...At least you can upvote though.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for (I presume) is sometimes called "macro substitution" and is not available in C#.  You *could* do something similar using reflection to find the property with the name that `localVariable` holds, but unless you've got dozens of properties to set and/or  you want to prevent having to change the switch whenever you add a property it's probably not worth doing.