# Check if a property exists in a class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I try to know if a property exist in a class, I tried this :

```
public static bool HasProperty(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
}
```

I don't understand why the first test method does not pass ?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_HasProperty_True()
{
    var res = typeof(MyClass).HasProperty("Label");
    Assert.IsTrue(res);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test_HasProperty_False()
{
    var res = typeof(MyClass).HasProperty("Lab");
    Assert.IsFalse(res);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the relevant code from `MyClass`?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Your method looks like this:

```
public static bool HasProperty(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
}
```

This adds an extension onto `object` - the base class of *everything*. When you call this extension you're passing it a `Type`:

```
var res = typeof(MyClass).HasProperty("Label");
```

Your method expects an *instance* of a class, not a `Type`. Otherwise you're essentially doing

```
typeof(MyClass) - this gives an instanceof `System.Type`.
```

Then

```
type.GetType() - this gives `System.Type`
Getproperty('xxx') - whatever you provide as xxx is unlikely to be on `System.Type`
```

As @PeterRitchie correctly points out, at this point your code is looking for property `Label` on `System.Type`. That property does not exist.

The solution is either

a) Provide an *instance* of MyClass to the extension:

```
var myInstance = new MyClass()
myInstance.HasProperty("Label")
```

b) Put the extension on `System.Type`

```
public static bool HasProperty(this Type obj, string propertyName)
{
    return obj.GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
}
```

and

```
typeof(MyClass).HasProperty("Label");
```

Comment: i.e. your code is looking for` Type.Label`, not `MyClass.Label`.

Comment: How would one put this on the extension System.Type where would that be found/. Where does this go in the code to execute?

Comment: @Demodave - extension methods are just in a public static class. See here for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: If you get this error: "Type does not contain a definition for GetProperty" then read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858469/missing-type-getproperty-method-in-windows-8-developer-preview

Comment: typeof(TEntity).HasProperty doesn't exist

Comment: @Demodave In this question, the OP had written that as an extension method. Read the question.

Answer (score 31):

This answers a different question:

If trying to figure out if an OBJECT (not class) has a property,

```
OBJECT.GetType().GetProperty("PROPERTY") != null
```

returns true if (but not only if) the property exists.

In my case, I was in an ASP.NET MVC Partial View and wanted to render something if either the property did not exist, or the property (boolean) was true.

```
@if ((Model.GetType().GetProperty("AddTimeoffBlackouts") == null) ||
        Model.AddTimeoffBlackouts)
```

helped me here.

Edit: Nowadays, it's probably smart to use the `nameof` operator instead of the stringified property name.

Comment: Regarding the use of the `nameof` operator, will it work (not thrown an exception) to get the name of a property that may not exist? Since the premise of the original question was that we don't know if this property exists?

Comment: Why don't you try it and then edit my answer to clarify?

Answer (score 5):

I got this error: "Type does not contain a definition for GetProperty" when tying the accepted answer.

This is what i ended up with:

```
using System.Reflection;

if (productModel.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(propertyName) != null)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possibilities.

You really don't have `Label` property.

You need to call appropriate [GetProperty overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx) and pass the correct binding flags, e.g. `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance`

If your property is not public, you will need to use `BindingFlags.NonPublic` or some other combination of flags which fits your use case. Read the referenced API docs to find the details.

EDIT:

ooops, just noticed you call `GetProperty` on `typeof(MyClass)`. `typeof(MyClass)` is `Type` which for sure has no `Label` property.

Comment: The default binding flags used are `Instance|Public|Static`, iirc.

Comment: @LukeH, I wasn't sure, so I wrote 'correct' and added 'e.g' :) maybe the `Label` is private property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding like I was:

```
<%# Container.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty("Property1") != null ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Property1") : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Property2")  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of the context on why this was needed, so this may not return enough information for you but this is what I was able to do:

```
if(typeof(ModelName).GetProperty("Name of Property") != null)
{
//whatevver you were wanting to do.
}
```

In my case I'm running through properties from a form submission and also have default values to use if the entry is left blank - so I needed to know if the there was a value to use - I prefixed all my default values in the model with *Default* so all I needed to do is check if there was a property that started with that.