# How can I test if an object has a property and set it?

Tags: c#

I have this code in C#

```
foreach (var entry in auditableTableEntries)
{
  IAuditableTable table = (IAuditableTable)entry.Entity;
  table.ModifiedBy = userId;
  table.ModifiedDate = dateTime;
  if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
  {
    if (table.CreatedBy == null || table.CreatedBy == null)
    {
      table.CreatedBy = userId;
      table.CreatedDate = dateTime;
    }
  }
}
```

Some of the table objects have a property `modified` and for these I would like to set the property to the value of number of seconds. Since 1970.  Something like:

```
table.modified = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds
```

But how can I tell if the table has that property? I don't want to set the property if it does not exist as I assume that would cause an exception.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
if (table.GetType().GetProperty("modified") != null)
{
  // The following line will not work as it will report that
  // an IAuditableTable does not have the .modified property
    
  table.modified = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds
}
```

But the problem with this is that table.modified is not valid syntax as IAuditableTable does not contain a modified property.

Comment: Related (not quite duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/test-if-a-property-is-available-on-a-dynamic-variable

Comment: You can cook up something using reflection, but there is a bit of a code smell in your question. Why is `Modified` not a property on `IAuditableTable`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a property exist in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341028/check-if-a-property-exist-in-a-class)

Comment: @CompuChip - sometime in the future it might be but for now I don't want to change 30+ tables and a lot of code :-)

Comment: Use refelction var myproperty = table.GetType().GetProperty("modified")

Comment: You mean you don't want to fix your design now but later when there is even _more_ code depending on it?

Comment: Well you could always have another interface, `IModificationRecord` or something, and check whether `table` implements that interface...

Comment: @Hakunamatata - Thanks, this is what I was able to find also. But how can I set that property?  table.modified will not work as a way to set it.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I like your idea. Actually I was not aware I could have more than one interface at a time. Now I tried to code a solution using GetType but I came across a problem when trying to set the property.

Comment: if(myproperty !=null && myproperty.CanWrite)
{
    myproperty.SetValue(table, value, null);
}               https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using reflection:

```
PropertyInfo propInfo 
    = table.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("modified ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

// get value
if(propInfo != null)
{
    propInfo.SetValue(table, DateTime.Now);
}
```

Or as others have pointed out, you would better have your class implement another interface, eg `IHasModified` and:

```
if(table is IHasModified)
{
    (table as IHasModified).modified = //whatever makes you happy. ;
}
```

Comment: But how can I set the value as it reports  IAuditableTable does not contain a modified property