# Does model contain an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a shared view that is used by 4 different parent views.  In the shared view, I need to do a simple check:

```
if (Model.foo == barr)
   {...]
```

The problem is, in one of the 4 models, there is no foo.  I'd rather not add it to the one model to just avoid the error:

> does not contain a definition for 'foo'

I'm wondering if I can do a pre-check, something like..

```
if (Model.Contains(foo) && Model.foo == bar)
{...}
```

Is anything like that possible?

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341028/check-if-a-property-exist-in-a-class)?

Comment: If they share something in common you should use an contract to establish a relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection, if you want to check if an object contains a property:

```
if ((typeof(Model)).GetProperty("foo") && Model.foo == bar)
```

but it seems a bit awkward the whole thing. Basically, I have never seen reflection to be used in a View.

Comment: yeah, it does seem awkward.  Thank you for this answer.  I'll mull it over.  I may need to rethink how I'm using this shared view.

Comment: You are welcome ! I think that you should reconsider the purpose of this shared view.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around that seems to be pretty good.  In each of the four models, i added a property:

```
public int MySharedViewSource { get; set; }
```

And then in the view...

```
if (Model.MySharedViewSource == 1}
  { 
      // Wnatever is in here only gets executed if the source is 1,
      // so I can reference Model.foo and not worry about errors 
      // when using this shared view from a model that does not have foo in it.
  }
```