# How to handle a bool if it doesn't exist?

Tags: c#

I have created a simplified scenario below of my problem. I need to set EmptyBookingAllowed to `true` or `false`, however `AllowEmptyBooking` will not exist in the config for certain customers.

How do I set `EmptyBookingAllowed` to `true` if the config.AllowEmptyBooking otherwise set it to the value of `config.AllowEmptyBooking`.

```
public Class BookingSession()
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public bool EmptyBookingAllowed {get; set;}
}

BookingSession session = new BookingSession(){ 
    Username            = "whatever",  
    EmptyBookingAllowed = config.AllowEmptyBookings
};
```

Comment: Does config.AllowEmptyBookings allow for the concept of "not defined", or will it then have a default value of "false"?

Comment: If the `config` is `null` when it does not exists... Then like this `EmptyBookingAllowed = config?.AllowEmptyBookings ?? true`

Comment: How is your config class and how is your config class mapped? Making config.AllowEmptyBookings nullable like `bool?` and doing a null check while settings EmptyBookingAllowed may help

Comment: verify if property exists
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15341181/5605739

Comment: you need `EmptyBookingAllowed ` to be a nullable type `bool?`.

Comment: What is the type of `config`? And what is the type of `config.AllowEmptyBookings`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Null-coalescing operator:

```
EmptyBookingAllowed = (config?.AllowEmptyBookings ?? true);
```

Comment: it's not work for empty config. Better use `(config?.AllowEmptyBookings ?? true)`

Comment: It should be `config?.AllowEmptyBookings ?? true` (`?.` instead of `?`): note, that if `AllowEmptyBookings` is `bool` it always exists, while `config` can be `null`

Comment: Just to clarify, config will always exists, however config.AllowEmptyBookings may not always exist.

Comment: @joehelsing Then you need to use `bool?` instead of `bool` for the `AllowEmptyBookings` in your config class.

Comment: @joehelsing if it is a  `bool` and not a `bool?` (nullable), then it _always_ exists.

Comment: But I think it is better to intercept non-existent config case in the code that actually loads the config... In there, if config does not exists, you can populate it with the defaults (instead of making fields nullable)... That will make your code that actually uses config simpler.